# Holding horizontal and vertical lines while measuring in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, measurements, vertical

Is it possible to hold horizontal and vertical (similar to Ortho mode from Autocad) lines while using the measurement tool in QGIS?

Comment: but when measuring in QGIS what are you calling horizontal and vertical ? is it north-south and east-west ? if that's the case are you aware that depending on the projection (and the scale) these direction may not be parallel to the screen side or even being straight line ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's possible unfortunately.

What you could do is create a scratch layer with line-type geometry and create a new feature with Advanced Digitizing turned on. This will allow you to draw horizontal and vertical lines and will display the distance as well. Not exactly what you're looking for but probably the closest to it.